# iOS - Download and play audio file with AVAudioPlayer in the same time from buffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, afnetworking, avaudioplayer

I have a bit complex situation where I need to play an audio stream from some URL.
First I need to send some cookies along with the URL request and the stream that is coming back must be played with `AVAudioPlayer`.
So it is possible to use `AFNetworking` or standard `NSURLConnection` to send the cookies and save the stream to a temporary file and then play it? But can be done async? I mean once the stream is receiving data also the player must start, so not to wait for finishing the download because it can be a large file.